# how to use google spreadsheet api for the private spreadsheet In Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets

I have been struggling for a while just one small authorization problem. so I am able to get an access_token with auth 2.0. and I tried to pull data from the private spreadsheet. There are several challenge.
   When I read the google spreadsheet API. For private, I might need an OAuth 2.0 authorization or google API Key.
So I used OAuth, now have an access_token. I put https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{{spreadsheet_id}}/values/{{spreadsheet_name}}!A1:D3?access_token=" +gDriveKey.clientID
Consequence => the error msg (I need to put API Key).

So I create an API Key on API Manager -> credential

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{{spreadsheet_id}}/values/{{spreadsheet_name}}!A1:D3?access_token=" +gDriveKey.clientID + "&key="+gDriveKey.apiKey
Consequence => the error msg (The caller does not have permission) status : "403".

and I believe I give the right permission scope on the OAUth 
  My scope was: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

Can you guys please tell me what was the problem??
Thank you.